# IIS Not Accepting Active Directory Login Credentials

Tags: security, asp.net, iis7

I have an ASP.NET web form using Microsoft's boilerplate Active Directory login page, [set up exactly as suggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Windows Authentication is activated on the "Default Website" and "MyWebsite" levels, and `Domain\This.User` is given "Allow" access to the site. After entering the valid credentials for `This.User` on the web form, a popup window appears asking me to enter my credentials yet again. Despite entering valid credentials for `This.User` (after attempting `Domain\This.User` and `This.User` formats), it rejects the credentials and returns an unauthorized security headers page (error 401.2). Active Directory user `This.User` is valid, the IP address of the AD server has been verified and SPN's have been set up for the server.

Error Code: 0x80070005

Default Web Site security config:

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

Sub web site security

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
    <forms loginUrl="~/logon.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: Please include things like log reports, and configurations.